# Criar um video pelo javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reprodutor-de-video

Eu tentei criar um vídeo na minha página que é gerado pelo clique do botão através do javascript, como segue no código:

```js
function tocar_video(mysrc){
 var video = document.createElement('video');

 video.src = mysrc;
 video.autoplay = true;
}
```

```css
.bt202{
 background-image:url("https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/botao-de-play_318-42541.jpg");
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input class="bt202" id="00202" type="button" onclick="tocar_video('http://somesite.com/somevideo.mp4');"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas não tive êxito para fazer o vídeo aparecer, alguém saberia apontar o problema?

Comment: Vc quer por o vídeo dentro do input?

Comment: https://videojs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que você quer adicionar ele a algum lugar, se for isto então tem que usar [**`appendChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) para adicionar a um local desejado da página, por exemplo:

```js
var lastVideo;

function tocar_video(mysrc){
    if (lastVideo && lastVideo.stop) {
         lastVideo.stop(); //Para o video anterior
    }

    var video = document.createElement('video');

    video.src = mysrc;
    video.autoplay = true;

    var videoContainer = document.querySelector("#video-container");

    videoContainer.innerHTML = ""; //Limpa elementos dentro do container ou video anterior

    videoContainer.appendChild(video);

    lastVideo = video; //Define para poder ser parado se trocar de video
}
```

```css
.bt202{
 background-image:url("https://image.freepik.com/icones-gratis/botao-de-play_318-42541.jpg");
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<input class="bt202" id="00202" type="button" onclick="tocar_video('https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4')">

<input class="bt202" id="00203" type="button" onclick="tocar_video('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Video_animation_gyroscope_precession.ogv');">

<input class="bt202" id="00204" type="button" onclick="tocar_video('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Animation_of_Rotating_Earth_at_Night.webm')">

<input class="bt202" id="00205" type="button" onclick="tocar_video('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Animation.ogv');">

<!-- Container aonde vai ser adicionado o video -->
<div id="video-container"></div>
```

Comment: Sim, obrigado, resolveu o problema. Mas desse modo é possível manipular as medidas, controls e outras funções ?
Eu tentei algo como `videoContainer.setAttribute("width","400");` e não funcionou

Comment: @Dr.G adicione no `video` o `setAttirbute` e não no `videoContainer`